# RoadElement.getPermanentDirectedLinkId() always returns 0

Tags: android, here-api

For some reason, this code always returns 0, no matter where I am

```
public Long getClosestLinkID()
{
    GeoCoordinate cur = HereMapsManager.instance.getPositionAnchor(); //returns my current position
    Long closest = -1L;

    RoadElement closest_elem = RoadElement.getRoadElement(cur, "fre");
    if (closest_elem != null) {
        closest = closest_elem.getPermanentDirectedLinkId();
    }

    return closest;
}
```

It finds a valid RoadElement, but calling getPermanentDirectedLinkId() (or getPermanentLinkId()) constantly returns 0.

Now, the documentation says:

```
Returns:
Permanent Link ID with direction of this element or 0 if not available.
```

So I tried with random coordinates on the map a little bit everywhere on the roads in France, and it keeps returning 0. I'm lost here.

Comment: did u check  whether HereMapsManager.instance.getPositionAnchor() return correct value ?

Comment: Yes it does. I also checked with other values taken from Google Maps located on highways and various types of roads in the country.

Answer (score 0):

getPermanentDirectedLinkId and getPermanentLinkId property is unavailable when the public transport mode RouteOptions.TransportMode#PUBLIC_TRANSPORT is used. For all the other transport modes, it is available only in routes calculated with the online connectivity mode. You should set your Connectivity explicitly to ONLINE(setConnectivity(Connectivity.ONLINE)).

Also, check if  you are in one of the below two modes:

1. Tracking - NavigationManager.startTracking()
2. Navigation - NavigationManager.startNavigation()

This is required inorder to map match your location to a route.

You have to explicitly download and use offline maps as well to get this information.

Editing to add more information based on the customer comment below: You can check the classes and methods supported for your SDK by looking up the below pages

- Starter SDK: {SDK-Download-location}/HERE_Android_SDK_Starter_v3.8_65/HERE-sdk/libs/docs/mapsdoc/index.html
- Premium SDK: {SDK-Download-location}/HERE_Android_SDK_Premium_v3.8.0.104/sdk/HERE-sdk/libs/docs/mapsdoc-hybridplus/index.html

Comment: My connectivity was set to OFFLINE. That's where the problem was. Thank you.

Comment: Wait... nope, still not working. I sent a mail to the customer service. They said it's because I was using the freemium option :/

Comment: Can you try the above suggestions made ? Also make sure you are using premium sdk.

Comment: I'm using startNavigation(), RouteOptions.TransportMode#CAR, I downloaded the map of the whole country (and I'm using it, and it's up to date), and I'm using the Android Premium SDK v3.9.

Comment: Could you check if the getPermanentLinkId() and  getIdentifier() are being returned ? I believe the getPermanentDirectedLinkId() are only available when the RoadElement is part of a Route, i.e If you do a route calculation and then go through the RoadElements of the route you should get the  getPermanentDirectedLinkId().

Comment: getPermanentLinkId() returns 0 as well. getIdentifier() works normally.

Comment: How about when you iterate through the route response ? Are the ids also 0 in that case ?